# Delete the first row of each duplicate row

Tags: excel

So I have a strange issue where I have a database with a column for email addresses that contain many duplicates. I need to delete the first instance of each email address, but keep all of the remaining duplicates. Is this possible?

I also need unique rows to be removed as well.

Comment: Surely you have a field (aka *key*) that could provide sorting where the results show the record you wish to retain first. After that, Data ► Remove Duplicates.

Comment: There are some addresses that are there 4 or 5 times, though

Answer (score 2):

We start from the bottom and work upwards.  If the value exists above, leave the row.  If the value does not exist above, but exists below, delete the row.:

If we start with:

[image]

and run this macro:

```
Sub KleanUp()
   Dim N As Long, v As String, i As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction
   Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
   Dim rLookUp As Range, rLookDown As Range

   N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   For i = N To 2 Step -1
      v = Cells(i, 1).Text
      Set rLookUp = Range("A1:A" & i - 1)
      Set rLookDown = Range("A" & i + 1 & ":A" & N)
      If wf.CountIf(rLookUp, v) > 0 Then
      Else
         If wf.CountIf(rLookDown, v) > 0 Then
            Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
         End If
      End If
   Next i

   If wf.CountIf(Range("A2:A" & N), Cells(1, 1).Text) > 0 Then
      Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
   End If
End Sub
```

We will end up with this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without at least a minimum sample of redacted data and with no specifics as to the column that contains the email addresses it is difficult to be exact but this may perform as requested.

```
Sub del_first()
    Dim rw As Long, iEMLcol As Long

    iEMLcol = 1   'define the column that holds the email addresses. This is column A

    With ActiveSheet  'define this worksheet properly!!
        For rw = .Cells(Rows.Count, iEMLcol).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            If (Application.CountIf(.Columns(iEMLcol), .Cells(rw, iEMLcol).Value) > 1 And _
              Application.CountIf(.Columns(iEMLcol).Resize(rw, 1), .Cells(rw, iEMLcol).Value) = 1) Or _
              Application.CountIf(.Columns(iEMLcol), .Cells(rw, iEMLcol).Value) = 1 Then
                .Rows(rw).Delete
            End If
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```